# Create C# object using Object object = new(); versus var object = new Object();

Tags: c#

I am working with an existing C# codebase that is initializing a lot of objects using what seems to be a generic `new()` command that doesn't include the object type. I am coming from Java to C#, and I have always used the `= new Object()` approach.

Here are the two different approaches for creating objects in the code. Both appear to be used inconsistently through the codebase.

```
var object1 = new Object();
Object object2 = new();
```

I have read up creating anonymous objects in C# using the syntax `new{ }` but I can't find much on just using new with parens for initialization.

All the code is doing at this point is initializing new instances of these objects for later use. Following the debugger through, it appears as if both approaches result in identical objects. However, is it truly the case that both approaches are equivalent? Is there any reason why I should be using one of these approaches versus the other, either technically or as a best practice professionally?

Comment: This isn't Blazor-specific - it's just a new C# 9 feature, target-typed "new" expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. new () is a syntactic sugar introduced in C# 9. Neither of the constructors in your example creates anonymous objects. The choice of syntax is really up to your coding style.

Comment: If multiple developers work on the project though - it might be good to agree on one or the other for consistency.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator, _"Beginning with C# 9.0, constructor invocation expressions are target-typed. That is, if a target type of an expression is known, you can omit a type name"_. It's not an anonymously typed object; the compiler deduced the type of object to create from the type of variable to which it is assigned. Both of your expressions are equivalent to `object obj = new object();`

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you all. I knew that I wasn't actually creating anonymous objects since they were actually typed in the line, but all of the information that was turning up in searches was around anonymous and `new{ }` objects. I hadn't come across this target-type reference.

Comment: @Evk Agreed--This project is being reworked, and future consistency is a goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end result is absolutely the same IL code. So if we are talking about any performance difference - [there is no difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#new-operator). It's just a "syntax sugar" to let us write code more conveniently.

As for what is worth to use, first of all, use that way which is already used in your project. Don't mix up different styles. If you've just started your project then as for me it's better to use the full name of a type, it's easier to read and understand. But it's on you, you can google any C# Coding Conventions and follow it throughout the project.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is kind of a placeholder. If the ***object***-type is known to the compiler you may use var as a placeholder. I personally try to not use it too often as I find the coding to be less clear and debugging harder.

Example:

```cs
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

similarly (beginning from C# 9.0), the object type may be omitted from object creation if the ***variable***-type is known:

```cs
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new ();
```

To conclude:
In your case, where empty objects are newly created in variables, it does not make a difference. They both do exactly the same, they are just switched vice versa. It is merely a convenience feature. That beeing said, a convenience feature while writing code, but a pain when coming back to a project and trying to understand whats going on.

```
# all the same:
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new ();
```

However, in code you would use `var` for *creating* a new *variable* while using `new()` for *assigning* a *new empty object* to a variable:

```
# creates variable Object[] and assigns a value
var inhabitants = allInhabitants.ToArray();

# assigns an empty object to variable
Object[] inhabitants = new();
```

More details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator

Comment: Thanks, Julian, I appreciate the response. I should have been more clear in my question, however. I am familiar with `var`, but I had confusion specifically around the `new()` portion, which you addressed a bit in your second code block.

Comment: what I wanted to say is: They are the same, just vice versa. Making it easy to write, but a pain to debug and read if you come to the project later

Answer (score 1):

As it was told already it is  C# 9's new feature. It is a matter of style to use or not to use it, code behind will be absolutely the same.  But be carefull, I noticed a small syntax pitfall , but it also shows the difference between the anonymos types and this new c# feature

```
    var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4}; //OK
    List<int> list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4}; //OK
    List<int> list = new() {1,2,3,4}; //OK
    List<int> list = new {1,2,3,4};  // Error, anonymos type !!!
```